# Big Query | Show Max Value in each row based on shared value in another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm analyzing purchase data and looking into Rebuy Rates by SKU. My data looks something like this so far:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the **max value** from each column into every row (based on the email address). Something like this:
[image]

Any ideas on how to do this? Is there a way I can get the max value of the last 3 columns based on email address into each row?

Comment: can you present your samples as a text (not as image) please. also clarify logic - i didn't get it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email, first_item_purchased, 
  MAX(purchases_within_90_days) OVER(PARTITION BY email) AS purchases_within_90_days, 
  MAX(purchases_within_180_days) OVER(PARTITION BY email) AS purchases_within_180_days, 
  MAX(purchases_within_270_days) OVER(PARTITION BY email) AS purchases_within_270_days
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row email       first_item_purchased    purchases_within_90_days    purchases_within_180_days   purchases_within_270_days    
1   abc@gmail   null                    1                           1                           2    
2   abc@gmail   product_1               1                           1                           2    
3   abc@gmail   product_2               1                           1                           2    
4   def@gmail   null                    0                           2                           3    
5   def@gmail   product_1               0                           2                           3    
6   def@gmail   product_2               0                           2                           3
```

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15